# when I pay my total amount the change is negative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a transaction billing. My error is once the patient paid the bill about the amount of procedure is to be done so the error is that when the patient pays the total amount the change is negative

[image]

```js
$(function() {
  $("#edit_payment").on("keydown keyup", sum);

  function sum() {
    var textValue1 = document.getElementById('edit_payment').value;
    var textValue2 = document.getElementById('edit_amount').value;
    if (textValue1 > textValue2) {
      document.getElementById('edit_balance').value = "0";
      document.getElementById('edit_change').value = textValue1 - textValue2;
    } else if (textValue1 < textValue2) {
      document.getElementById('edit_change').value = "0";
      document.getElementById('edit_balance').value = textValue2 - textValue1;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <strong>Amount (US$) </strong>: <input type="text" name="edit_amount" id="edit_amount" />
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Payment (US$)</strong>: <input type="text" name="edit_payment" id="edit_payment" />
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Change (US$) </strong>: <input type="text" name="edit_change" id="edit_change" />
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Balance (US$)</strong>: <input type="text" name="edit_balance" id="edit_balance" />
</p>
```

Comment: The maths is correct, so this is a business logic question. Do you want to disallow overpayments, or automatically detect them and alert the user?

Comment: Hello, sir what you recommend here? because I'm a newbie here

Comment: here you are subtracting the minimum value from greater value so the negative sign is appearing if you want remove that then you have to change the if condition

Comment: what condition sir? I don't know how to do

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Although the maths is correct, the operations are being performed on strings, not numbers (`'600' > '1000'` is true).

Comment: else if (textValue1 < textValue2) here you are subtracting from greater value like 400 -1000 so you getting -400 as a result if you want it in positive you have to change the conditions other way around

Comment: For the maths to work correctly you'll need to convert the string values (`'600'` and `'1000'` in your example) to numbers `textValue1 = Number.parseFloat(textValue1);` etc

Comment: oh nice that works thanks phuzi 
I really learned a lot here on this site :)

Answer (score 1):

Although the maths appears correct, you are performing the comparisons on string values not numbers. In this context `'600'` is "greater than" `'1000'`, so the logic appears reversed.

Parse the values first as numbers `Number.parseFloat()` first.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#edit_payment").on("keydown keyup", sum);

  function sum() {
    var textValue1 = Number.parseFloat(document.getElementById('edit_payment').value);
    var textValue2 = Number.parseFloat(document.getElementById('edit_amount').value);
    if (textValue1 > textValue2) {
      document.getElementById('edit_balance').value = "0";
      document.getElementById('edit_change').value = textValue1 - textValue2;
    } else if (textValue1 < textValue2) {
      document.getElementById('edit_change').value = "0";
      document.getElementById('edit_balance').value = textValue2 - textValue1;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <strong>Amount (US$) </strong>: <input type="text" name="edit_amount" id="edit_amount" />
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Payment (US$)</strong>: <input type="text" name="edit_payment" id="edit_payment" />
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Change (US$) </strong>: <input type="text" name="edit_change" id="edit_change" />
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Balance (US$)</strong>: <input type="text" name="edit_balance" id="edit_balance" />
</p>
```

Comment: you should add code if both amount are equal

Answer (score 0):

> You should warn the user for this

```js
$(function() {
  $("#edit_payment").on("keydown keyup", function(){
    var payment = Number($('#edit_payment').val());
    var amount = Number($('#edit_amount').val());
    if(amount < payment ){
    alert('Paying amount more than Assigned amount!' );
    $('#edit_payment').val(amount);
    $('#edit_change').val(0);
    }else{    
    var change  = amount - payment;
    $('#edit_change').val(change); 
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <strong>Amount (US$) </strong>: <input type="text" name="edit_amount" id="edit_amount" />
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Payment (US$)</strong>: <input type="text" name="edit_payment" id="edit_payment" />
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Change (US$) </strong>: <input type="text" name="edit_change" id="edit_change" />
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Balance (US$)</strong>: <input type="text" name="edit_balance" id="edit_balance" />
</p>
```

Comment: instead of warning you can show the balance in change / balance are per logic